# Do a request cURL in php, using ip of PROXY LIST - webshare.io?

Tags: php, curl, web-share

Hi I'm trying to use a proxy list ip to make a request to a website, but I can't. I keep getting an error in the cURL request in php.
Where am I doing wrong ?

```
$ request = curl_init ('https://www.webisite-request.com/');
curl_setopt ($ request, CURLOPT_PROXY, '102.xxx.xx.xx');
curl_setopt ($ request, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'user: password');
curl_setopt ($ request, CURLOPT_PORT, 5725);
curl_setopt ($ request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
'Authorization: Token qiwnnqncnqiomcoiemcoq',
"Content-Type: application / json",
"Accept: application / json",
"Accept-Language: it-it",
"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
"Origin: https://www.webisite-request.com/",
));
curl_setopt ($ request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ request, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$response = curl_exec ($ request);
curl_close ($ request);
```

i'm using **webshare.io** but i don't understand where is the problem

Comment: May help to include the error text/code in the question.

Comment: how can i show it ?

Comment: i think is a problem about webshare :( maybe i must do add other

Comment: You can show the error to us by editing your question and pasting it in

Comment: @ADyson http status code is 00

Comment: @NigelRen http status code is 00

Comment: Where did you get that from exactly? Have you tried using curl_error? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: @ADyson curl-error return nothing, i used $http_status = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); to gett http_status (so 00)....

Answer (score 0):

set the proxy port like this:

```
curl_setopt ($ request, CURLOPT_PROXY, '102.xxx.xx.xx:5725');
```

don't use CURLOPT_PORT